# Rewrite url in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is it possible for .htaccess to hide subdirectories in url after rewrite? I am able to permanently hide index.php in my URL but Im having hard time with longer ones. 
This is what I'm trying to achieve.

So website should accept /login url
`https://example.com/login?param=abc&paramb=123`, and it should internally go to
`https://example.com/core/auth/login?param=abc&paramb=123`
but not showing this odd-looking url in the browser. I want the `core/auth/` be like the index.php that becomes invisible permanently the address bar.

```
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /core/auth/login [R,L]
```

Below is my code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

#my code here...
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /login 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /core/auth/login [R,L]
```

Comment: `/core/auth/login` - this isn't a valid end point, do you mean `/core/auth/login.php` or something?

Comment: It's a controller function. I use an MVC framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/core/auth/login` isn't really the URL you should be rewriting to as this still needs additional rewriting in order to be processed (it's not the final end-point). It would seem from your existing directives that you are using path-info on the `index.php` script to pass the requested URL-path to your framework. eg. `index.php/core/auth/login`. So try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle requests to "/login"
RewriteRule ^login$ index.php/core/auth/login [L]

# Framework
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Although I think it would be preferable to create an additional route in your framework, rather than using `.htaccess` for this?